# Getting undefined method content_for()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, actionview

my mac just broke and I had to migrate to an Ubuntu machine. I am working on an app that is already on production on an Ubuntu machine as well.

I cloned this app into my new machine and all the view helpers seems to go missing, btw I am ussing HAML.

I ran my specs and I am getting tons of :

> undefined method url_for for #
>   undefined method t for #
>   undefined method content_for for #
>   undefined method form_for for #

Here are the contents of my Gemfile: http://gist.github.com/563759

I've removed all gems from my new machine and reinstall them using bundler to match my production environment.

I also use rvm, I don't know what additiona info may be relevant

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but why did you add the `:require => nil` line in your Gemfile? Doesn't this mean it will **NOT** load Rails resulting in the missing methods you see above?

Also, are you using the same version of Bundler? Bundler recently got upgraded to 1.0 maybe the previous `bundle install` was using an older version?

Comment: Well rails is being loaded in config/environment.rb:

RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

I've been using bundler for a while and I always do this, beside this app works ok in production.

I will give it a try

Comment: Great! I am back on track. Uninstalling bundler 1.0 and reinstalling 0.9.26 solved the issue. Apparently there is some kind of bug in bundler 1.0

Thanks!!